# What is known about Renyi entropy of a probability density function?

Tags: statistical-mechanics, quantum-information, entropy

I see most discussions about [Renyi entropy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/R%C3%A9nyi_entropy) to be using either of these two kinds of definitions, for $\alpha > 0, \alpha \neq 1$

- $H_{\alpha}(p_i)=\frac{1}{1-\alpha}\log \sum p_i^{\alpha}$ for a probability measure over a discrete set of events indexed by $i$.

or,

- $H_\alpha(\rho)=\frac{\ln\mathrm{tr}(\rho^\alpha)}{1-\alpha}$ when a physical system is described by a density matrix $\rho$.

Q1 : In the language of probability measure spaces is it clear as to what is that underlying structure in the second kind of definition?

Q2 : For a continuous probability density function has one thought of quantities like $H_\alpha (f) = \frac{1}{1-\alpha}\log [ \int f(\vec{x})^\alpha d\vec{x} ] $ ? (If yes, then can someone point to some reference?)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a reference for the continuous versions:

http://arxiv.org/abs/1402.2966

Comment: Larry, the reference is good, but can you try to summarize the relevant answer rather than just giving a reference?

Comment: This does not suffice as an answer. You must summarize or explain the basic points in the link AND how they ANSWER the question.

Comment: Thanks for the reference. Any reason why this definition is not popular in physics?